# System of equations

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to find ALL or a list of possible values for x satisfying: x MOD 9 ==2 AND (x+631) MOD 9 = 3  Using Mathematica. can anyone help? 2 is not the only answer 497 is another one since 497 mod 9 = 2 and 497 + 631 = 1128----- 1128 mod 9 = 3

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. It is advised that you show some prior attempts of solving your problem. To give you some starting point: ``FindInstance[Mod[x, 9] == 2 && Mod[x + 631, 9] == 3 && x < 100, x, PositiveIntegers, 100]``? This gives all positive solutions to your equations, smaller than 100.

Comment: Ok thank you  very much

Answer (score 6):

If you replace "Mod" by x== .. + 9 a1 you may use Reduce and solve for x. And as MMA assumes all variables to be complex, you must define the variables as integers E.g.

```
Reduce[{x == 2 + 9 a1 && 631 + x == 3 + 9 a2, {x, a1, a2} \[Element] 
   Integers}, x]
```

[image]

where c1 is an arbitrary integer.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {9*m + 2 == x, 9*n + 3 == x + 631};
```

To just find examples, use [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html)

```
FindInstance[eqns, {x, m, n}, NonNegativeIntegers, 10] // Sort

(* {{x -> 2, m -> 0, n -> 70}, {x -> 803, m -> 89, n -> 159}, 
    {x -> 4772, m -> 530, n -> 600}, {x -> 4790, m -> 532, n -> 602}, 
    {x -> 5744, m -> 638, n -> 708}, {x -> 5780, m -> 642, n -> 712}, 
    {x -> 5969, m -> 663, n -> 733}, {x -> 6923, m -> 769, n -> 839}, 
    {x -> 7346, m -> 816, n -> 886}, {x -> 8084, m -> 898, n -> 968}}
```

To find all solutions

```
sol = Solve[eqns, {x, m, n}, NonNegativeIntegers]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
And @@ Assuming[C[1] ∈ Integers && C[1] >= 0, 
  eqns /. sol // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

The first ten solutions are

```
Table[sol /. C[1] -> c, {c, 0, 9}]

(* {{{x -> 2, m -> 0, n -> 70}}, {{x -> 11, m -> 1, n -> 71}}, 
    {{x -> 20, m -> 2, n -> 72}}, {{x -> 29, m -> 3, n -> 73}}, 
    {{x -> 38, m -> 4, n -> 74}}, {{x -> 47, m -> 5, n -> 75}}, 
    {{x -> 56, m -> 6, n -> 76}}, {{x -> 65, m -> 7, n -> 77}}, 
    {{x -> 74, m -> 8, n -> 78}}, {{x -> 83, m -> 9, n -> 79}}}
```

**EDIT:** Or directly solving the [`Mod`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod.html) expressions

```
Solve[{Mod[x, 9] == 2, Mod[x + 631, 9] == 3}, x, 
 NonNegativeIntegers][[1]]
```

[image]